# Excel VBA - Select Entire Rows In-Between 2 Named Cells or Rows for Sorting

Tags: excel, vba, select

New to macros in Excel.

My worksheet named "OVERALL" has projects listed out in rows with various data in columns. I'm trying to create macro buttons that sort the projects based on the various data cells.

Since I will be adding projects to the group frequently and didn't want to update the macros with the correct cells to sort, I've been trying to use Named Cells or Named Rows but have gotten in a rut.

The projects I add sometimes have to be at the very beginning, very end or somewhere in the middle so I've defined upper and bottom border rows to help the macro identify where the data selection starts and stops. In the macro, I'm hoping to be able to select the entire rows in-between the border rows in case additional data columns are added in the future.

If I record a macro, this is the code I get;

`Sub SortProjectNameA2Z()

```
Rows("14:149").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OVERALL").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OVERALL").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A14:A149"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OVERALL").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A14:W149")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("A11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False`
```

Row 14 is the entire row below the Upper Border Row = "BorderFirstRow".

Row 149 is the entire row above the Lower Border Row = "BorderLastRow"

I've also named the first cell of the Upper Border Row as "BorderCellFirst" and the first cell of the Lower Border Row as "BorderCellLast" if that helps?

I've found a way to select the rows *between* the border rows; `Range("BorderCellFirst:BorderCellLast").EntireRow.Select`
but I haven't found a way to select the entire rows *in-between* the border rows or border cells that did not include the border rows.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
With Worksheets("OVERALL")
    With .Range(.Cells(.Range("BorderFirstRow").Row + 1, "A"), _
                .Cells(.Range("BorderLastRow").Row - 1, "W"))
        .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End With
```

To sort with secondary keys,

```
With Worksheets("OVERALL")
    With .Range(.Cells(.Range("BorderFirstRow").Row + 1, "A"), _
                .Cells(.Range("BorderLastRow").Row - 1, "W"))
        .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, "A"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
              Key2:=.Cells(1, "C"), Order2:=xlDescending, _
              Key3:=.Cells(1, "B"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End With
```

Sort on column A as primary then column C then column B.

This method of sorting only allows up to three keys but you can pre-sort on additional secondary keys first.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, that worked.  It's way over my head so I'll try researching to learn.  If I want to change the column that is sorted do I just change the Cells(#)?

Comment: No, that was shorthand for the cell in the top-left corner of the range and probably should have included the column number as well like `.cells(1, 1)`. To change the key1 column to W you would use `.cells(1, 23)` or perhaps `.cells(1, "W")`.

Comment: Can I add a secondary Sort by adding another line .Sort Key2:= or how does that work?

Comment: Did you inadvertently erase the comma? `.Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, "B"), Order1:=xlAscending, _` works for me.

Comment: Yes, my fault.  I had edited my question to a new once I saw that.  Trying to add a secondary sort and should be good to go.  Really appreciate your time.

Comment: BTW, what kind of Jeep?  I DD a '85 CJ7.

Comment: Started my addiction with an '86 CJ (last year with removable doors) and now a '97 TJ (first year with round headlights after YJ). Been building it and wrecking it for about 12 years now.

Comment: How do I sort on column C and then secondary level column B?

Comment: `Key1:=.Cells(1, "C"), Order1:=...` then `Key2:=.Cells(1, "B"), Order2:=...` get rid of the key3 line.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm topless and doorless most of the time thanks to our weather.  No AC, no heat and no power brakes but easily choose it over our luxury sedan...

Comment: Just curious, do you carry a copy of the exclusion regulation that states you don't need doors? I used to and had to use it twice to get out of a ticket when driving in the city.

Comment: No I don't.  From what I've studied, it's legal in Texas.  I've read of others in different states having issues though.

Comment: Yes, it's legal because they came with removable doors. Legal on the left coast of Canada as well. However, that doesn't prevent a ticket unless you can prove on the roadside that you are exempt. Worked for me.

Comment: Guess the cops are pretty cool around my area then.  I nervously approached 4 of them standing around my CJ and overhead them comment about how awesome it would be to patrol in it.  In 6 years I haven't had any issues.